# What is expected value of a sample mean?

Tags: probability, expectation, statistical-inference, sampling

Let $X_1,. . . , X_n$ be a random sample from a population with variance $σ^2$ and mean $μ$. Designate the corresponding sample mean by $\bar{X}$. Show that $\mathbb{E}(X_i\bar{X})=σ^2/n + µ^2, i = 1, . . . , n.$
Help please! Can't do anything.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. But I came to $σ^2+µ^2$.

Comment: Start by using the linearity of the expectation operator and assume the sample values $X_i$ are independently distributed.  Keep in mind that the sample mean $\overline{X}$ includes a factor $1/n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some $i \in \{ 1, \dots, n\}$,
$$X_i\bar{X}=\dfrac{X_1X_i+X_2X_i+\cdots+X_{i-1}X_i+X_i^2+X_{i+1}X_i+\cdots+X_nX_i}{n}$$
Now for some $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$, where $j \neq i$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[X_jX_i]=\mathbb{E}[X_j]\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\mu^2$$ due to independence (random sampling). Furthermore, $\mathbb{E}[X_i^2] = \sigma^2+\mu^2$.
Hence, 
$$\mathbb{E}[X_1X_i+X_2X_i+\cdots+X_{i-1}X_i+X_i^2+X_{i+1}X_i+\cdots+X_nX_i]=(n-1)\mu^2+\sigma^2+\mu^2$$
which simplifies to 
$n\mu^2+\sigma^2$.

Now multiply by $\dfrac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @AndriyRussu If my answer was helpful, please click the checkmark next to my answer. This will encourage people to answer your future questions.